# How to get two different keys inside a foreach keySet()?

Tags: java

I want to print the keys of my HashMap "allDishes".
This HashMap contains an Dish as the value.
The Dish class has a HashMap field named "Ingredients".

I want to print the key of the "allDishes" and the keys of its HashMap "Ingredients".

With the foreach keySet(),
the key for Ingredients is "null",
because there is no value in "Ingredient" like there is in "allDishes".
Is it possible at all to print keys of different HashMaps?

```
Map<String, Dish> allDishes = (Map<String, Dish>) application.getAttribute("allDishesHashMap");

for (String key : allDishes.keySet()) { 
    Map <String, String> Ingredient = allDishes.get(key).getIngredients(); 
    out.println("<li><b>" + key + "</b> with: </li>" + Ingredient.get(key));
}
```

Comment: Follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

Currently,
you are iterating through the keys of the allDishes HashMap.
What you want to do is iterate through the keys of the allDishes HashMap and
for each key in the allDishes HashMap,
iterate through the keys of Ingredient HashMap contained within the current dish in the allDishes HashMap.

To do this,
first iterate through the allDishes entrySet,
then iterate through the ingredients keySet for each entry.

Here is some code:

```
final Map<String, Dish> dishMap = (Map<String, Dish>)application.getAttribute("allDishesHashMap");

for (final Map.Entry dishEntry: dishMap.entrySet())
{ 
  final Map <String, String> ingredientMap = dishEntry.getIngredients();

  out.println("<li><strong>" + dishEntry.getKey() + "</strong> Ingredients: <ul>");

  for (final String ingredientName : ingredientMap.keySet())
  {
    out.println("<li>" + ingredientName + "</li>")
  }

  out.println("</ul></li>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print them with nested loops and a null check.

```
Map<String, Dish> allDishes = (Map<String, Dish>) 
application.getAttribute("allDishesHashMap");

for (String dishKey : allDishes.keySet()) { 
    Map <String, String> ingredients = allDishes.get(dishKey).getIngredients(); 
    System.out.println("Dish Key: " + dishKey);
    // check if null here, if necessary
    if (ingredients == null) {
        continue; // continue, or print something else. whatever you need
    }
    for (String ingredient : ingredients.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Ingredient Key: " + ingredient);
    }
}
```

You can also print a "keyset" directly like the following if you don't need any special formatting on the keysets.

```
Map<String, Dish> allDishes = (Map<String, Dish>) 
application.getAttribute("allDishesHashMap");

for (String key : allDishes.keySet()) { 
    Map <String, String> ingredients = allDishes.get(key).getIngredients(); 
    System.out.println("Dish Key: " + key);
    // check if null here, if necessary
    if (ingredients == null) {
        continue; // continue, or print something else. whatever you need
    }
    System.out.println("Ingredients KeySet: " + ingredients.keySet());
}
```